# Issue with own health indicator. Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create my own health indicator by aligning multiple images which represent one percent. So basically, based on the current health, I align as many one-percent parts as needed. However, removing them seems to be a problem.

```
-(void)updateHealthIndicator:(ccTime)delta{

    //getting health and healthReduction (removed for better readability). This part does not affect the functioning of the loop...


    if(health-healthReduction > 0 ){
        NSLog(@"updatehealthindicator called ! health = %d ", health);
        health -= healthReduction;

        [self removeChildByTag:1000 cleanup:YES];
        for (int i = health; i>0; i--){ 
            onePercent = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"onepercentofhi.png"];
            onePercent.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
            onePercent.position = ccp(880+(-onePercent.contentSize.width) * i,712 );
            [self addChild:onePercent z:2 tag:1000];

        }



}
```

The health indicator shows up, but it only seems to remove the first "one-percent" piece. Are all sprites with tag 1000 affected by this `[self removeChildByTag:1000 cleanup:YES];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one view with the given tag is removed.

However, you could extend CCNode with the following code to remove all children

```
-(void) removeChildrenByTag:(int)aTag cleanup:(BOOL)cleanup
{
    NSAssert( aTag != kCocosNodeTagInvalid, @"Invalid tag");
    int w=[children count]-1;
    while(w>=0){
        CocosNode *node=[children objectAtIndex:w];
        if( node.tag == aTag ){
            [self detachChild:node cleanup:cleanup];
        }
        w--;
    }
}
```

Note: This is a [proposed solution](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=337) to be integrated into Cocos2D but hasn't made it yet.